# Windows 8.1 -- disable touch screen?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

My computer comes with a touch screen.  I may want that someday, but right now I don't.  Is there a way to disable it?  I am running Windows 8.1.  Thanks!

EDIT:  When I go to Pen and touch via control panel, this is what I see.  There is nothing about using my fingers as input

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Start the Device Manager, e.g., through Control Panel, or by running `devmgmt.msc` from

- Start > Run, or
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or
- Command Prompt

Expand "Human Interface Devices" and disable the touch screen from there:

[image]

Be careful to not shutdown your keyboard and/or mouse!

Comment: I see an option to disable my screen.  But will that stop it from displaying anything?  That would be bad . . .

Comment: No, don't disable anything under display adaptor, it should be under human interface device.

Comment: Yes, under Human Interface Devices, I can disable the screen or not.  But it doesn't say anything about touch there.  So I don't know if it will disable the screen completely, or just turn off touch.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>
2. Type Control Panel
3. Go to Hardware and Sound
4. Pen and touch
5. Click the touch tab
6. Disable use your finger as an input

[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-tms/disable-the-touchscreen-for-a-windows-8-laptop/ca7baeb9-66f3-43d4-ac4e-2be90d55591d)

Comment: -1. The question includes a screenshot of the control panel item you direct us to. As you can see there is no obvious way to disable the finger as input. [I see the same as the questioner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bJKX2.png); on the touch tab shown in the screenshots, where would you "Disable use your finger as an input"?

Comment: I agree with @dumbledad. The page this answer links as a reference also suggests disabling the touch input device in the Device Manager, which has more "helpful" votes than any other answer.

Comment: Apologies kobaltz, I realise that the screen-shot was added four days after the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a touch screen device with PowerShell.  Here is a code snippet that works on Windows 10.

```
# Get 'Plug & Play' (PNP) devices by name
$devices = Get-PnpDevice  | where friendlyname -like "*touch*" 

# Disable devices
$devices | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
# Enable devices
$devices | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

for earlier windows releases you can use WMI to get the same devices:

```
gwmi Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Where-Object { $_.DeviceName -like "*touch*" }
```