# How do I disable the touch screen on Windows 8.1 for a Lenovo X220?

Tags: windows-8.1, thinkpad, touchscreen

I would like to try disabling the touch screen on my Lenovo X220 to diagnose odd mouse jumps. Looking at Lenovo forum answers the way to do this is to 'Go to Control Panel "Pen and Touch" and uncheck "Use your finger for input" on the Touch tab'. However I do not see such a check-box:

[image: screenshot of touch control panel]

How do I disable touch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 -- disable touch screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/659757/windows-8-1-disable-touch-screen)

Comment: It looks like it, but that question wasn't answered either.

Comment: Also, your link doens't seem to go where you say it should.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Just because the existing answers on the question aren't satisfactory, doesn't make it a different question.  Also, the link to that question goes to that question (system generated), so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @techie007, sorry my second comment was directed towards dumbledad and the link he provided in his post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't disable it through the control panel, you can disable it through the Device Manager.

- Open a Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).
- Type in: `devices.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Find this device under `Mice and other pointing devices`:

[image: Mice and other pointing devices]

- Right Click and choose disable. This should fix your issue.

[Disabling touch on Windows 8 on a Lenovo X220 tablet](http://sachachua.com/blog/2013/02/disabling-touch-on-windows-8-on-a-lenovo-x220-tablet/)

Comment: this doesn't work. The touch screen is reenabled after reboot/sleep etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Control Panel → Hardware and Sound → (Devices and Printers) 
   **Device Manager**
2. Human-Interface Devices
3. Right click on **HID Compliant touch screen** and choose **Disable**
4. You may enable it later by the same way.

[image: HID Compliant touch screen]