# How do I convince my computer my touchscreen doesn't exist?

Tags: touchscreen, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have a [Lenovo IdeaCentre B540](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/ideacentre/b-series/b540/) with a cracked touchscreen. Its digitizer rapidly registers clicks around the region of the crack, and fails to recognize any other touch input. This makes the touchscreen useless (in fact, rather detrimental) to the operation of the computer.

Now, there are [many](https://superuser.com/questions/692250/how-do-i-disable-the-touch-screen-on-windows-8-1-for-a-lenovo-x220) [references](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaCentre-Desktops-Home-Servers/How-do-you-disable-the-touch-screen-Broken-and-handicapping/td-p/1057409) [demonstrating](https://superuser.com/questions/659757/windows-8-1-disable-touch-screen?lq=1) how to disable a touchscreen within Windows by disabling it in the Device Manager. I have used this method successfully in Windows 8. However, when it comes time to perform OS upgrades (say, to Windows 8.1 or a Linux distro), the new OS still recognizes the garbage input from the broken touchscreen, and I have to go through the tedious process of disabling it again while hoping that a mislaid click doesn't undo my efforts.

I would therefore like to get rid of the touchscreen once and for all, and *entirely convince my computer that it doesn't exist*. I would like for my computer to cease recognizing it as an input device, so that no OS can ever see it again.

Is what I'm describing here possible? There seems to be no BIOS option for it (the closest available disables all USB devices, which is obviously not desirable). The [maintenance manual](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_ideacentre_b540b540p_hmm_20120713.pdf) mentions a "touch control board"-- is it safe to simply remove this?

Comment: If it is a USB digitizer, you should be able to simply disconnect it internally (unless it is integrated into the board somehow). You could certainly try removing the "touch control board" (this would probably work, but I'm not familiar with that model).

Answer (score 0):

From the repair [manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_ideacentre_b540b540p_hmm_20120713.pdf):

```
Step 21. Remove the 9 screws that secure the chassis to the front bezel and lift it up.
Step 22. Disconnect the touch cable from touch control board.
Step 23. Disconnect the converter cable from LED panel. 
Step 24. Remove the Wi-Fi antenna from the front bezel.
Step 25. Detach the power board cable, front function board cable, front indicator board cable and LED
cable from the chassis.
```

Note step 22, you can see the cable can be disconnect which should still allow the machine to post (its not unlikely it will throw an error message *every* time you boot it). Step 25 makes it clear the other interconnects are separate. Following the manual the majority of the PC needs to be taken down to access this connector under the motherboard, if performing this task yourself allow a lot of time and a large workspace to lay out the daughter cards safely.