# Proper Registry Key Needed for Script to Disable/Enable Windows 10 Touch Screen

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, touchscreen, device-manager

I know that:

1. My Windows 10 Device manager has the "HID-compliant touch screen" hardware that I can [set to "disabled" to turn off my touch screen](https://superuser.com/a/693924/128824).
2. I can create [a short script in notepad to edit the Registry of a device](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-desktop/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-enabledisable-usb/00bc0f58-afc5-402c-8cb1-5c2cf2ddd1f4) (see Pathusclass's answer).

But **what registry key I would need to access and what value to set** it to in order to make such a short cut to disable/enable my touch screen?

Comment: Maybe this.  https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/101948-device-touchscreen-disablerenabler/

Comment: Does it have to be a script? Would you be opposed to a freeware tool that can do the same thing from the command line?

Comment: @BrianC: If you mean "by the command line" that I have to use it through the command line, then no. I want to essentially click on an icon to turn on and off (in this case, two icons  in order to open a notepad file). Really, what I am seeking is the proper registry key and variable to set, since I can follow the example to create my own. I just need the right location to enable/disable in the registry.

Comment: I don't think the examples in the page you linked will actually achieve this. I have no reason to believe that the registry entries for enabling the device as described there are for anything other than startup. I don't think you can use them to immediately enable/disable a device.

Comment: You can find your exact answer with described steps :https://winaero.com/blog/enable-or-disable-touch-by-finger-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

The beet way on a Windows 10 system is to use **PowerShell**.
[Get-PnpDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps) and [Disable-PnpDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/disable-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps) are the Cmdlets you'll need. You must use an *Administrative* PowerShell Console Window.

`Get-PnpDevice` returns all PNP devices:

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice                                                                                  
Status     Class           FriendlyName
------     -----           ------------
Unknown    DiskDrive       General UDisk USB Device
OK         System          Motherboard resources
OK         System          Motherboard resources
OK         System          Motherboard resources
OK         HIDClass        HID-compliant vendor-defined device
```

So we narrow it down with `Where-Object` (alias `?`):

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice | ?{$_.FriendlyName -match 'touch screen'}                                         
Status     Class           FriendlyName
------     -----           ------------
OK         HIDClass        HID-compliant touch screen
```

Then we pipe it to `Disable-PnpDevice`:

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice | ?{$_.friendlyname -match 'touch screen'} | Disable-PnpDevice

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Disable" on target "Win32_PnPEntity: HID-compliant touch screen (DeviceID =
"HID\VID_04F3&PID_24E3&COL01\6&34FA9EF5&...)".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
PS C:\>
```

If you wish to disable without cnfirmation, use the `-Confirm` parameter with a value of `$False`:

```
PS C:\> Get-PnpDevice | ?{$_.FriendlyName -match 'touch screen'} | DISable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$False
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a tool, [`devcon.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that they claim can enable/disable devices from the command line (or a batch script, or a shortcut, etc.). This may allow you to do what you want (without a registry key).